# How to create dynmaic pivot items for ItemsControl in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, itemscontrol, datatemplateselector

create Pivot control with dynamic pivot items, within the pivot datatemplate have to show Items control that too will have data template..like below

```
    <phone:Pivot x:Name="chatPivot" Margin="0 2 0 76" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" SelectionChanged="chatPivot_SelectionChanged">                       <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>                      
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="chatScroll" Margin="0,0,0,72"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <ItemsControl  Margin="0" x:Name="chats" Tap="chats_Tap_1" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource imgItemTemplate}"  ItemsPanel="{StaticResource imgItemPanel}">
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </ScrollViewer>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot>
```

Here is my dataTemplate.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="imgItemPanel">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="imgItemTemplate" >

        <chatbubble:ChatBubbleControl x:Name="ChatBubble" Hold="ChatBubbleControl_Hold_1"  />

    </DataTemplate>

    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: What do you need to do?

Comment: Actually am having an itemsControl which is having datatemplate . That Items control use in Pivot control which is having dynamic Pivot Items.Pivot Items are generating dynamically but ItemsContol not populating the data what could be the reason?..

Comment: can you please show me your datatemplate of itemscontrol?

Comment: <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="imgItemPanel">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="imgItemTemplate" >

            <chatbubble:ChatBubbleControl x:Name="ChatBubble" Hold="ChatBubbleControl_Hold_1"  />

        </DataTemplate>  </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>    Here chatbubble is an usercontrol.

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia Have you seen my comment?.

Comment: I answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually do not know the design of your "ChatbubbleControl" usercontrol but I found one issue why values are not getting bound.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="imgItemPanel">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="imgItemTemplate" >

    <chatbubble:ChatBubbleControl x:Name="ChatBubble" xyz="{Binding}" Hold="ChatBubbleControl_Hold_1"  />

</DataTemplate>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

You are binding value to ItemsControl but you are not binding any value to actual control (here, chatbubblecontrol) that is displaying the value on screen.
The solution is the you need to create a property to your usercontrol e.g.: Here, I made a test property named "xyz". and then try to bind the values to it.

Hope this will help you conceptually.

Comment: Without using Pivot control my Items control showing data properly.. I just placed that ItemsControl into Pivot control..So am not thinking so binding chatbubble as you shown.